# PHPUnit doesn't see changes in fixtures

Tags: php, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3.4 project with PHPUnit 5.7.0 and make extensive use of fixtures. Now I notice that when I change something in the structure of a fixture, for instance adding a new field, PHPUnit doesn't see it. The only resolution I have found so far is rebooting.

Is there some sort of caching going on? Is there a way to force PHPUnit to reload the fixtures?

Comment: A fixture should clear the database before running. Can you provide the code for you fixture and the test please

Comment: It's a whole bunch of code so I'd need to do a lot of pruning before I can post online. Are you talking about setUp() and tearDown()? I assume the database clear is done in the tests, and not the fixtures, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures do clear the data before injections, but I am not sure they clear the schema as well.

When this happened to me I had to clear the orm cache with

`bin/cake cache clear_all`

Otherwise, regardless of my schema changes in the fixtures, they would still use the cached schema, from before the changes.

Rebooting is kind of strange solution for me, unless you're using some sort of in memory cache instead of disk cache.

Comment: Clearing cake cache seems to work, thanks! Didn't think of doing that. The fact that rebooting worked seems to suggest that Cakephp does use some sort of in memory cache?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking about when I wrote the last line in the answer. Perhaps you are using APC or MemCache in your app.php file? Or writing on the disk in a location that gets cleaned after a reboot?